# Why am i getting segmentation fault in C code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int t,i,rem,l[i],b[i];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for (i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&l[i],&b[i]);
    }

    for (i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        if (l[i] > b[i])
        {
            rem = l[i]/b[i];
            rem +=1;
            printf("%d \n",rem);
        }
        else if (l[i] > b[i])
        {
            rem = b[i]/l[i];
            rem +=1;
            printf("%d \n",rem);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("1 \n");
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Hi my code is getting compiled but not running due to a segmentation fault. Please help me in figuring out whether its become of some memory issue or scanf statements

Comment: Seems you are new to C. Let me guess your origins: Pascal/Delphi?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int t,i,rem,l[i],b[i];
```

`i` is not initialized and you are creating arrays of size `i` (what's the value of `i` currently?). Arrays are of fixed size and it won't change when the value of `i` changes.

Fix the problem by changing

```
int t,i,rem,l[i],b[i];
```

to

```
int t, i, rem;
```

and add

```
int l[t], b[t]; /* You want arrays of `t` size */
```

after

```
scanf("%d",&t);
```

so that `t` gets initialized when the VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) are created.